# Promise returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I'm trying to build an API using the http module and AWS, but when I try to call it, it doesn't return anything. I'm trying to get the request body and convert it to json data.

The promise I made to convert a request body to json is this.

```
export const useMarshall = (req: IncomingMessage) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
    req.on("data", (chunk: Uint8Array) => chunks.push(chunk));
    req.on("end", () => resolve(JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString())));
  });
```

I call it in this manner, but nothing is returned.

```
createServer(async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
  HTTPController.useGET("api/entry", req, res, async () => {
    //first try
    await useMarshall(req)
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("data");
      });
    //second try
    const data = await useMarshall(req);
    console.log(data);
  });
}).listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listener connected to http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

My class is called HTTPController.

```
export class Controller implements ControllerInterface {
  async useGET(
    uri: string,
    req: IncomingMessage,
    res: ServerResponse,
    callback: () => void
  ) {
    if ((req.url as string).match(`/${uri}(.*?)`) && req.method === "GET") {
      const converted_data: object | any = await useToJSON(req);
      const validated_data: object | any = useEntryScheme(converted_data);

      if (validated_data.error) {
        res.writeHead(400, useHeader);
        res.write(JSON.stringify({ message: validated_data.error.message }));
        res.end();
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    }
  }
}

export const HTTPController = new Controller();
```

I'm new to http modules and don't understand how promises work, so I'm hoping someone could assist me.

Comment: You can read the `req` stream only once. It won't fire a `finish` event twice. You're waiting for something that never occurs.

Comment: What is `HTTPController.useGET` and what does it do?

Comment: Hi @Bergi I updated my question, you can check it out.

Comment: It seems like `useToJSON(req)` reads the request body, and my first comment applies.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for making me aware that I could just call a callback with a parameter passed to it.